# Confluent - Splitting Avro messages from one kafka topic into multiple kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have an incoming kafka topic with **multiple** Avro schema based messages serialized into it.

We need to split the messages in Avro format into multiple other kafka topics based on certain value of a common schema attribute.

```
                             |------> [OUTGOING TOPIC(AVRO) - A] 
[INCOMING TOPIC(AVRO)] ----->|------> [OUTGOING TOPIC(AVRO) - B]
                             |------> [OUTGOING TOPIC(AVRO) - C]
```

Would like to understand how to achieve it while avoid building an intermediate client to do this splitting/routing in confluent platform.

I explored the kafka connector but did not find an existing connector which does this work.

Comment: You can either use KSQL or Kafka Streams.

Comment: KSQL might not work, because the input topic does not have one schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a Kafka Streams application and use `branch()`:

```java
KStream input = builder.stream("topic");
KStream[] splitStreams = input.branch(...);
splitStream[0].to("output-topic-1");
splitStream[1].to("output-topic-2");
// etc.
```